# Why setInterval is not working properly after a while?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a javascript code to show users a random quote every 10 second. I use jquery to update the div and setInterval to repeat the action. I'm fetching a random quote from a javascript array.

But when i tested this, it seems, it is not working properly after a while (like 3-5 mins) , I have some jquery effects like fadeIn and fadeOut but they are executed before the quote changes. Here is the js code;

```
var quotes = [
    "Some String",
    "Some String",
    "Some String"
];

$(function() {
    var $rand = $('div#randomQuote > p');
    var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];     
    $rand.html(random_quote);
    $rand.animate( {"opacity" : 0}, 0);
    $rand.animate( {"opacity" : 1}, 500);
    $rand.delay("9000");
    $rand.animate( { "opacity" : 0 }, 500 );    
});


function randomQuote () {
    var $rand = $('div#randomQuote > p');
    var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 
    $rand.html(random_quote);
    $rand.animate( {"opacity" : 1}, 500 );
    $rand.delay("9000");
    $rand.animate ( {"opacity" : 0}, 500 );
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(randomQuote, 10000);
});
```

Although I'm not sure, I think, these lines take some time to calculate and it breaks the loop.

```
var $rand = $('div#randomQuote > p');
var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
```

**Q:** How can i improve this code to get it working as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the problem isn't your code. Often the browser doesn't execute scripts (and thus animations), when the window isn't focused. You should consider stopping all animations on the `blur` event of the window and restart it on `focus`.

Comment: Codereview is for reviews of working code. Not for getting help to get code to work. For questions like this, you should go to Stack Overflow (where I'll now move this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way your queue of events will grow indefinitely. What you want to use in this case is probably setTimeout instead of setInterval. I suggest to try this link: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: thanks for taking time,
but, with setTimeout, my function runs only once, where i want it to loop forever

Comment: oh wait, i see arguments.callee in your link, now it seems to work as i want, i will test and let you know how did it go :)

Comment: Please notice that setTimeout in the example is called recursively, as opposed to setInterval.

Comment: sadly, this is still buggy :/ if i keep surfing on other pages and come back to my script after a while, animations still executed at wrong times.